# How to schedule a celery task without blocking Django

Tags: django, mongodb, django-rest-framework, celery, scheduled-tasks

I have a Django service that register lot of clients and render a payload containing a timer (lets say 800s) after which the client should be suspended by the service (Change status REGISTERED to SUSPENDED in MongoDB)

I'm running celery with rabbitmq as broker as follows:

celery/tasks.py

```
@app.task(bind=True, name='suspend_nf')
def suspend_nf(pk):
    collection.update_one({'instanceId': str(pk)},
                          {'$set': {'nfStatus': 'SUSPENDED'}})
```

and calling the task inside Django view like:

api/views.py

```
def put(self, request, pk):
    now = datetime.datetime.now(tz=pytz.timezone(TIME_ZONE))
    timer = now + datetime.timedelta(seconds=response_data["heartBeatTimer"])
    suspend_nf.apply_async(eta=timer)
    response = Response(data=response_data, status=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
    response['Location'] = str(request.build_absolute_uri())
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally find a work around, since working on a small project, I don't really need Celery + rabbitmq a simple Threading does the job.

Task look like this :

```
def suspend_nf(pk, timer):
    time.sleep(timer)
    collection.update_one({'instanceId': str(pk)},
                          {'$set': {'nfStatus': 'SUSPENDED'}})
```

And calling inside the view like :

```
timer = int(response_data["heartBeatTimer"])
thread = threading.Thread(target=suspend_nf, args=(pk, timer), kwargs={})
thread.setDaemon(True)
thread.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking that your view blocks totally or view is waiting the "ETA" to complete the execution?
 
Did you receive any error?

Try using `countdown` parameter instead of `eta`.
In your case it's better because you don't need to manipulate dates.
Like this: `suspend_nf.apply_async(countdown=response_data["heartBeatTimer"])`
Let's see if your view will have some different behavior.

Comment: No I'm not trying to block the view, I want the view to launch in background the task to modify MongoDB later and immediately return Response without blocking